# World Marine Regions & Subregions Polygons

Tags: geospatial

I'm looking for a set of world marine regions & subregions to help augment some analyses I'm doing with the ASAM database. I found the following:

[image]

at http://fas.org/irp/world/para/docs/geol_geo.htm but I'm at a loss as to where the shapefiles are (and I did "google-the-heck" out of this so please post the google terms you used if that's how you ended up finding it).

Answer (score 4):

So, I managed to determine that NIMA is directly associated with the NGIA and I found a GitHub org for NGIA: https://github.com/ngageoint?page=1

There's an iOS app repo there - https://github.com/ngageoint/anti-piracy-iOS-app which had a CSV file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngageoint/anti-piracy-iOS-app/master/Asam/subregions.csv

That CSV file is a set of "spatial lines" for framing the sub-regions. I had to modify the subregions (I put the modified file in this gist) to remove duplicate IDs.

The R script (below) will convert the CSV tile to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and also uses the `geojsonio` package to make a geojson file of the SPDF (which is also in the repo).

Thank you to everyone who went on the hunt! It's really weird this shapefile wasn't in any catalog (it wasn't in any of the links here).

```
library(sp)
library(stringr)

dat <- readLines("subregions.csv")

SpatialPolygons(lapply(dat, function(x) {

  region <- str_split_fixed(x, ",", 2)[,1]
  poly_pts <- as.numeric(str_split(str_split_fixed(x, ",", 2)[,2], ",")[[1]])
  poly_mat <- matrix(c(poly_pts, poly_pts[1], poly_pts[2]), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
  tmp <- poly_mat[,2]
  poly_mat[,2] <- poly_mat[,1]
  poly_mat[,1] <- tmp
  Polygons(list(Polygon(poly_mat)), ID=region)

}), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat")) -> subr

subr_dat <- data.frame(id=sapply(subr@polygons, function(x) { slot(x, "ID") }),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rownames(subr_dat) <- subr_dat$id

subr <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(subr, subr_dat)

plot(subr)

library(geojsonio)
geojson_write(subr, geometry="polygon", file="subregions.geojson")
```

results in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/472f548d8d4ac84b6eb4)

Comment: you should post this to opendata se repo on datahub.io

Answer (score 3):

i think marine regions has what you want:
http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php

there's also marine data literacy:
http://www.marinedataliteracy.org/layers_list.htm

noaa.gov also has an exhaustive list of gis data, as well as natural earth and marinecadastre.gov
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/
http://www.noaa.gov/
http://marinecadastre.gov/data/